# How have Ad Mob Ads only appear on certain scenes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I have a game with Ad Mob Ads. I am using SpriteKit. The ads work perfectly but I only want them to appear in certain scene. For example have them disappear in the game scene. My ad banner is set up as follows. In my main.storyboard I have a 320x50 UIView that is connected to a GADBannerView in my GameViewController. Everything works perfectly fine, but in every scene there is a banner ad. How can I make the banner only appear in the main menu scene and game over scene. These are SKScenes. Please help! Thanks!

p.s. I am using Swift

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to implement that:

In your ViewController.swift, define

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAd:", name: "gameStateOff", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideAd:", name: "gameStateOn", object: nil)
```

Use these to communicate between your scene and your view controller.

Next, implement the showAd and hideAd functions, that will be called when your scene enters or leaves 'gaming state':

```
func showAd(notif: NSNotification) {
    // this func places the ad to the bottom of the screen
    var frame = ad.frame
    frame.origin.x = view.bounds.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2
    frame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - frame.size.height
    ad.frame = frame
  }

  func hideAd(notif: NSNotification) {
    // this func places the ad outside the screen
    var frame = ad.frame
    frame.origin.x = view.bounds.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
    ad.frame = frame
  }
```

where ad is your GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner).

Next add this to where you start the game

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("gameStateOn", object: nil)
```

This call makes the view controller execute hideAd function.

When you want to show the ad again, call

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("gameStateOff", object: nil)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! thanks man. Too bad the OP didn't mark it as the answer.